# javascript display elements on the page as they are appended

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display elements on the screen while new data is being loaded at the background asynchronously. My code works fine, however elements that are added to the screen are not being displayed until the code terminates. Here is an example:

```
var btn=document.createElement("button");
document.body.appendChild(btn);
sleep(1000);
var btn=document.createElement("button");
document.body.appendChild(btn);
```

The output of this code is, it waits for 1 seconds and adds both buttons at the same time. However I want it to add the first button, wait 1 sec and add the other one.

Any idea ?
Thanks

**Edit :** sleep() function isn't the case, it is only for helping me to explain the problem. The code above is not the one I'm using in my project. **In my project, I'm trying to print some feeds on the screen while new ones are being loaded.**

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What in the world is `sleep()`? That would be your problem.

Comment: What's the sleep function you're using? I wasn't aware JS had such a thing.

Comment: Is `sleep()` a JavaScript function?

Comment: There's no such thing as `sleep` in JavaScript. Any attempt to pause the `single-threaded` code execution will cause the entire page to freeze for the duration which is horrible for UX. What you want to use instead is `window.setTimeout(function(){},1000)`

Comment: In response to your edit and in addition to my comment, **DO NOT** force sleep your system!

Comment: Why re-create a function that comes out-the-box with JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

Use `setTimeout()` - I don't believe `sleep()` is a native function in JavaScript..

```
var btn=document.createElement("button");
document.body.appendChild(btn);
setTimeout(function(){
    var btn=document.createElement("button");
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
}, 1000)
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mLJkt/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var btn=document.createElement("button");
document.body.appendChild(btn);

setTimeout(function(){
    btn=document.createElement("button");
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
},1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

uhm i think "sleep()" is a JAVA not javascript method... however:

```
var btn=document.createElement("button");
document.body.appendChild(btn);
setTimeout(function(){
  var btn=document.createElement("button");
  document.body.appendChild(btn);  
},1000);
```

Some Doc:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

your `sleep()` function stop all JS script and exegute all 2 `document.body.appendChild(btn);` after sleep delay...